# Browser Image Cache issue with html5 Local Cache Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, browser-cache, cacheapi

I am using htlm5 "Cache Storage / Cache API" to store some large svg image game assets for an online html5 game. The Cache API feature works great.

When I need to make updates to these images, In my javascript I am able remove my old cache storage item and replace it with a new one by changing the Cache Storage key name/version number.  I have verified that my javascript removes the old Storage item (and its contained svgs) and replaces it with the new one without any intervention by the user.

The problem is that the some of the svg files appeared to be also stored in the regular browser cache and are not automatically replaced by the new versions stored in my html5 Cache Storage.
The only way I am able to get the browser to display the latest version of some of these images is to also manually clear the browser cache using the dev tools.

I need to be able to have the users get the latest images without them having to do anything.

Is there a method to tell the browser to not cache images/svgs that are already stored/cached within the html5 "Cache Storage"?

OR

Is there javascript method to clear the svg images from the regular browser cache, other than appending version numbers to each individual file I am storing in Cache Storage and my website?

Comment: Maybe [Cache.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete) ? [The main docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) also talks about how the Cache API affects the standard browser cache.